# iOS (Swift): Making Vibrant Button Flash with DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, subview, dispatch-queue

I'm trying to light up a bunch of vibrant `UIButton` subclass instances by calling the `flash()` method given by:

```
func flash(delay: TimeInterval = 0.0) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay)  { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        let flashView = UIView(frame: strongSelf.bounds)
        strongSelf.insertSubview(flashView, at: 0)
        flashView.backgroundColor = strongSelf.color
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { flashView.removeFromSuperview() }
    }
}
```

Using this function I can for-loop through an array of buttons triggering a flash effect that lasts for 0.1 seconds with the flashing caused by the vibrancy layer altering the `flashView` instance behind it.

Does this function have any drawbacks by calling `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` within a call to `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`?

Answer (score 0):

No , it doesn't as here no need for `[weak self]`  as this GCD ( Grand Central Dispatch ) doesn't cause retain cycles

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay)  { /*[weak self] in */
```

Check last section [Here](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/functional-programming-closure-reference-cycle-and-fix-f42cc53c6213)

Comment: Thanks.. what does *GCD* stand for please?

Comment: Try googling "ios GCD"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with nested calls to `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()`. However, each call to your flash function is creating and adding a new subview to your view. That will create an ever-increasing stack of subviews to accumulate as the animation runs (which will cause your memory usage to grow slowly until you free the button views.

You should refactor your flashing views to have an instance variable to a single subview and change it's color to cause a flash rather than adding a new one each time.

Comment: Thanks. Does the line `        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { flashView.removeFromSuperview() }` not remove the instance of `flashView` after 0.1 seconds? So the subviews won't continually add to the button?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed that bit. Indeed it will remove the subview.